# How to declare Postgres functional indexes in Sequelize model definition

Tags: sequelize.js

We have a Posgres functional index for a table and would like to have this declared in our sequelize table model definition.

When declaring the index as per below...

```
    indexes: [
      {
        name: 'coverage_segments_path',
        fields: ['ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(path, 4326), 3857)'],
        using: 'GIST'
      }
    ]
```

We get the following error when running the application...

`SequelizeDatabaseError: column "ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(path, 4326), 3857)" does not exist`

Is there a way to define functional indexes in Sequelize or is this not supported?